# Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)? At line under do while statement

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

I was creating a program that would take numbers in a file and average them and create the standard deviation; however, when I compile the program I get an error stating Unclassifiable statement at (1) which in the compiler it is located right under the do while statement. Does anyone have any input as to why this is? I am led to believe that I have incorrect syntax but not sure where.

```
implicit none

!declaring the single precision for real numbers, array, and variables.
integer :: firstnumber, i
real*4 :: average, sum_, standarddeviation

real*4, allocatable :: arrayone(:)!making sure that the array is single precision real

open(1,file='Numbers1.txt')!opening file

do i = 1, 10
    read(1,*) firstnumber!reading the first number
end do

allocate(arrayone(firstnumber))!allocating the array with the first number variable obtained from previous statement

i = 2

do while i < 60000 

    i = i + 1
    read(i,*)
    sum_ = Sum(arrayone) !sums all of the numbers from arrayone
    average = Sum_/float firstnumber !calculates the average or mean of the data set
    standarddeviation = sqrt(sum_ - average) * (sum_ - average)!calculates the standard deviation of the data set

print,"Average = "average
print,"Standard Deviation = "standarddeviation

deallocate(arrayone)!Deallocating arrayone}
close(1)

print*,"Done!"

end program Assignmentthree
```

Comment: The line should be `do while (i < 60000)`. Brackets aren't optional in Fortran `if` and `while` statements.

Comment: Thank you so much, but now I am having the same issue at the "average = Sum_/float firstnumber ", any ideas?

Comment: It is not related to the change that you suggested correct?

Comment: Do you mean `float(firstnumber)`? Note that in modern Fortran this should be `real(firstnumber, kind)`, where `kind` is the kind of real you want.

Comment: @veryreverie In modern Fortran (and even old Fortran), you simply divide by the integer.  Fortran has understood mixed-mode math for a few years now.